# In C# Why does using delegates allow threads to access form objects (like TextBoxes)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

From what I read , the definition of delegates is :

> A delegate is a type that references a method. Once a delegate is
>   assigned a 
>       method, it behaves exactly like that method. The delegate method can be used 
>       like any other method, with parameters and a return value.

Now I know how to write to form objects say a text box through threads using delegates however I fail to understand how the method that is addressed in the delegate could access
all the objects on the form. I would appreciate it if some one could clear this up.

Edit:
Now here is how I would create a delegate

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(string str,int str2);

void main()
{
Thread t = new Thread(RunInThread); //Method that will run in a separate thread
t.Start();
}
void RunInThread ()
{
MyDelegate delInstatnce = new MyDelegate(AddControl); //Attach a method
this.Invoke(delInstatnce,"First Parameter",1001);
}
void AddControl(string str,int str2)
{
  //Why could you access all the form components from here ?
}
```

Comment: People need to stop downvoting questions just because the asker is confused on the premises of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, that's a pretty confused description of delegates. You might find [my article on delegates and events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) more helpful.

Secondly, it's not quite clear what your question is about, given that the title and the body talk about different things.

A delegate is effectively just an object which encapsulates the idea of calling a method within a class. Accessibility to that method is controlled at delegate *creation* time, rather than at *execution* time - so for example, code within a class can create a delegate which refers to a private method, and that delegate can be returned to code outside the class... when it's invoked, the private method is invoked. This is still "safe" in terms of the access, because only code which has access to the private method is allowed to create the delegate instance. Within the private method, code has access to all other members in the normal way.

Now your title talks about threading... and using delegates doesn't *actually* allow you to access UI elements from non-UI threads. However, it allows you to use something like `Control.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.Invoke` which each invoke a delegate instance on the UI thread. So you're basically saying, "I need to run some code, but I want to run it on the right thread - please do it for me." A delegate is just the way you communicate which code you want to run on the UI thread.

Hope that helps. Feel free to ask for more specific clarification.

Comment: @Casper_2211: Well it's still not clear where threads come in, but this part of my answer is probably the most directly relevant: "Within the private method, code has access to all other members in the normal way." Why would you expect a private method *not* to have access to everything?

Comment: Thanks for your answer let me rephrase my question , If i had written something like  `some_textbox.text = "ABC"` inside `RunInThread` it would not have worked. Why did i have to use a delegate here to access form controls ?

Comment: @Casper_2211: That's the second part of my answer: you can't access UI components other than in the UI thread, and you use a delegate to provide a way of telling `Control.Invoke` what code you want to execute in the UI thread.